# Keras utilises less CPU when number of workers grows and numpy generates a large array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

My code uses a relatively extensive augmentation strategy, but I've noticed CPU utilisation isn't proportionate when `N` in `fit_generator(...workers=N)` increases. I have a 4-core CPU.

- When `N=1`, `htop` shows around 105% usage
- When `N=2`, `htop` shows around 202% usage
- When `N=3`, `htop` shows around 287% usage
- When `N=4`, `htop` shows around 342% usage

GPU usage is less than 40% throughout.

If I trim down the augmentation strategy to omit noise addition, I can achieve around 360% and higher GPU usage when `N=4`. Noise is added by

`x += numpy.random.normal(0, noise_sigma, x.shape) / 255.0`

where `x` is a 640x480 BGR input image. It is a slow call, averaging around 24.3ms per call, but shouldn't the CPU still do the work when `N=4`? How come numpy seems to be blocking other threads when it generates a large array of random numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`normal` calls `cont2_array*`

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1651

and there is a `lock`

Is this the reason?

Can you try to use individual `RandomState` to generate random numbers?

```
r = numpy.random.RandomState() 

.....

for ... :
    x += r.normal(0, noise_sigma, x.shape) / 255.0
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks. Can I ask why `numpy.random.normal` uses a lock? Since `RandomState.normal` appears to generate a normal distribution as well, should this be preferred over `numpy.random.normal`?

Comment: A (pseudo) random generator usually has internal states, which can not be accessed by different threads, so a `lock` must be used. `numpy.random` is a global `RandomState` (for handy usage) and shares the same internal state and lock. If you use `numpy.random` in a multi-thread environment, different threads try to acquire the shared lock and block others.